# Python wildcard search

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda python function that I inherited which searches and reports on installed packages on EC2 instances. It pulls this information from SSM Inventory where the results are output to an S3 bucket. All of the installed packages have specific names until now. Now we need to report on Palo Alto Cortex XDR. The issue I'm facing is that this product includes the version number in the name and we have different versions installed. If I use the exact name (i.e. Cortex XDR 7.8.1.11343) I get reporting on that particular version but not others. I want to use a wild card to do this. I import regex (`import re`) on line 7 and then I change line 71 to `xdr=line['Cortex*']`) but it gives me the following error. I'm a bit new to Python and coding so any explanation as to what I'm doing wrong would be helpful.

```
File "/var/task/SoeSoftwareCompliance/RequiredSoftwareEmail.py", line 72, in build_html
    xdr=line['Cortex*'])
```

```
import configparser
import logging
import csv
import json
from jinja2 import Template
import boto3
import re


# config
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


# @TODO
# refactor common_csv_header so that we use one with variable
# so that we write all content to one template file.

def build_html(account=None,
               ses_email_address=None,
               recipient_email=None):
    """

    :param recipient_email:
    :param ses_email_address:
    :param account:
    """

    account_id = account["id"]
    account_alias = account["alias"]

    linux_ec2s = []
    windows_ec2s = []
    ec2s_not_in_ssm = []
    excluded_ec2s = []

    # linux ec2s html
    with open(f"/tmp/{account_id}_linux_ec2s_required_software_report.csv", "r") as fp:
        lines = csv.DictReader(fp)
        for line in lines:
            if line["platform-type"] == "Linux":
                item = dict(id=line['instance-id'],
                            name=line['instance-name'],
                            ip=line['ip-address'],
                            ssm=line['amazon-ssm-agent'],
                            cw=line['amazon-cloudwatch-agent'],
                            ch=line['cloudhealth-agent'])

                # skip compliant linux ec2s where are values are found
                compliance_status = not all(item.values())
                if compliance_status:
                    linux_ec2s.append(item)

    # windows ec2s html
    with open(f"/tmp/{account_id}_windows_ec2s_required_software_report.csv", "r") as fp:
        lines = csv.DictReader(fp)
        for line in lines:
            if line["platform-type"] == "Windows":
                item = dict(id=line['instance-id'],
                            name=line['instance-name'],
                            ip=line['ip-address'],
                            ssm=line['Amazon SSM Agent'],
                            cw=line['Amazon CloudWatch Agent'],
                            ch=line['CloudHealth Agent'],
                            mav=line['McAfee VirusScan Enterprise'],
                            trx=line['Trellix Agent'],
                            xdr=line['Cortex*'])

                # skip compliant windows ec2s where are values are found
                compliance_status = not all(item.values())
                if compliance_status:
                    windows_ec2s.append(item)

    # ec2s not found in ssm
    with open(f"/tmp/{account_id}_ec2s_not_in_ssm.csv", "r") as fp:
        lines = csv.DictReader(fp)
        for line in lines:
            item = dict(name=line['instance-name'],
                        id=line['instance-id'],
                        ip=line['ip-address'],
                        pg=line['patch-group'])
            ec2s_not_in_ssm.append(item)

    # display or hide excluded ec2s from report
    display_excluded_ec2s_in_report = json.loads(config.get("settings", "display_excluded_ec2s_in_report"))
    if display_excluded_ec2s_in_report == "true":
        with open(f"/tmp/{account_id}_excluded_from_compliance.csv", "r") as fp:
            lines = csv.DictReader(fp)
            for line in lines:
                item = dict(id=line['instance-id'],
                            name=line['instance-name'],
                            pg=line['patch-group'])
                excluded_ec2s.append(item)

    # pass data to html template
    with open('templates/email.html') as file:
        template = Template(file.read())
        # pass parameters to template renderer
        html = template.render(
            linux_ec2s=linux_ec2s,
            windows_ec2s=windows_ec2s,
            ec2s_not_in_ssm=ec2s_not_in_ssm,
            excluded_ec2s=excluded_ec2s,
            account_id=account_id,
            account_alias=account_alias)

        # consolidated html with multiple tables
        tables_html_code = html

        client = boto3.client('ses')
        client.send_email(
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': [recipient_email],
            },
            Message={
                'Body': {
                    'Html':
                        {'Data': tables_html_code}
                },
                'Subject': {
                    'Charset': 'UTF-8',
                    'Data': f'SOE | Software Compliance | {account_alias}',
                },
            },
            Source=ses_email_address,
        )

        print(tables_html_code)
```

Comment: That is not the full error message.

Comment: `xdr=line['Cortex*']` Regex is not supported in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are getting a KeyError exception because Python does not support wildcards out of the box. A [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) creates a standard Python dictionary for each row in csv. Python's dictionary is just an associative array without pattern matching.

You can implement this by regex, though. If you have a dictionary `line` and you don't know the full name of a key you are looking for, you can solve it by [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) function.

```py
line = {'Cortex XDR 7.8.1.11343': 'Some value you are looking for'}
val = next(v for k, v in line.items() if re.search('Cortex.+', k))
print(val) # 'Some value you are looking for'
```

Be aware that this assumes that a `line` dictionary contains at least one item that matches the 'Cortex.+' pattern and returns the first match. You would have to refactor this a bit to change this.

Answer (score 0):

1. `import os` -  missing in the code
2. `def build_html(account=None` -> When the account is passed with `None` and below error will be thrown in `account["id"]` and `account["alias"]`.
   Ex:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pro\Documents\project\pywilds.py", line 134, in <module>
    build_html(account=None)
  File "C:\Users\pro\Documents\project\pywilds.py", line 33, in build_html
    account_id = account["id"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```